# Trying to Remove any non-numbers from an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get user input and then put this into an array, however, if the user puts in an element that is not a number how can I remove this? I can make an error message show up however the element still goes into the array.

```
      var input_array = [];

      var number = prompt('Enter a Number');
      if (isNaN(number)) {
        alert("Please Enter a Number");
      }
      var array = input_array.push(parseInt(number));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place the `push` inside an `else`. Also note that `push` returns the new length of the array - so `array` will be `1` in your code.

```js
var input_array = [];

var number = prompt('Enter a Number');
if (isNaN(number)) {
  alert("Please Enter a Number");
} else {
  input_array.push(parseInt(number));
}

console.log(input_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a neat way of doing it using the ternary operator. Only add the input to array if it is a number.

```
var input_array = [];
var number = prompt('Enter a Number');
isNaN(number) ? alert('Please Enter a number'): input_array.push(number);
```

Also prompt returns a string, so if you want your array to contain only numbers. Use parseInt when reading input

```
var number = parseInt(prompt('Enter a Number'));
```